# Linking multiple source from Access database to Excel file in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am trying to link two tables in Access to my Excel. One is Table_1 and the other is Table 2. But when I ran these codes, the two imported tables are linked to the same source, or say the same data source is imported twice. I tried to solve this problem by deleting the connection and re-connect it. But it does not work. The recorded macro use a line`Selection.ListObject.TableObject.Refresh`. But the system poped out an error stating that the object is not set when re-running the macro. Full code is below.

I would like to ask how to release the object and connect to another table under this case.

```
Sub Macro1()


Sheets("S6_Inforce").Select
Range("B1").Select
Workbooks("Lapse1709_ANALYSIS_v1_S6.xlsm").Connections.AddFromFile _
    "C:\Users\j1sunx\Desktop\201709_Lapse_redo\Step1_Analysis\Lapse Study 201709 S6.accdb" _
    , True, False
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=4, Source:=ActiveWorkbook. _
    Connections("Lapse Study 201709 S6"), Destination:=Range("$B$1")). _
    TableObject
    .RowNumbers = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshStyle = 1
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table__1__S6_Inforce_Summary"
    .Refresh
End With
Sheets("S6_Terminated").Select
Range("B1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Lapse Study 201709 S6").Delete
' Workbooks("Lapse1709_ANALYSIS_v1_S6.xlsm").Connections.Delete
' Selection.ListObject.TableObject.Refresh
Workbooks("Lapse1709_ANALYSIS_v1_S6.xlsm").Connections.AddFromFile _
    "C:\Users\j1sunx\Desktop\201709_Lapse_redo\Step1_Analysis\Lapse Study 201709 S6.accdb" _
    , True, False
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=4, Source:=ActiveWorkbook. _
    Connections("Lapse Study 201709 S6"), Destination:=Range("$B$1")). _
    TableObject
    .RowNumbers = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshStyle = 1
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table__2__S6_Terminations_Summary"
    .Refresh
End With
Range("F10").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: I know that ADODB could solve this problem, I am just curious how to solve this by using the trditional AddFromFile method.